# How to read the contents of active directory using python-ldap?

Tags: python-2.7, python-ldap

My script is like this:

```
import ldap, sys
server = 'ldap://my_server'
l = ldap.initialize(server)
dn="myname@mydomain"
pw = "password"
l.simple_bind_s(dn,pw)
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS,0)
print "valid"
```

I am using Python 2.7 on windows.

Is there any method to read or get the contents of active directory?

Answer (score 4):

You can do quite a lot also using `win32com.client` (which I had trouble finding documentation for). For example I've needed to resolve user email knowing his [`ADS_NAME_TYPE_NT4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) formatted name (`doman\jonjoe`).

First of all you need to convert it to `ADS_NAME_TYPE_1779` format (`CN=Jeff Smith,CN=users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com`):

```
name_resolver = win32com.client.Dispatch(dispatch='NameTranslate')
name_resolver.Set(3, 'domain\\jonjoe')
ldap_query = 'LDAP://{}'.format(name_resolver.Get(1))
```

Once you have that you can simply call `GetObject()`:

```
ldap = win32com.client.GetObject(ldap_query)
print(ldap.Get('mail'))
```

<sub>Tested with Python 3.2.5</sub>

Comment: Can this library also resolve a foreign security principal's domain originating in a different forest connected through a one way trust?

Comment: @AndrzejBobak it basically just wraps WinAPI so if you can write it in WinAPI, you can rewrite it using `win32*` python libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You should realy need to read the documentation of python-ldap http://www.python-ldap.org/docs.shtml

```
You have a connection in your variable l, then you can do this.

l.con_search_s('dc=your,dc=base,dc=dit', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, 'uid=*', ['uid', 'uidnumber'])

The above code, goint to search in to all the uid's entrys, for if entry, is going to get the uid and the uidnumbre attributes.
```